# Finding out the reason of delay between request and response time using apache spark mllib

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, machine-learning, delay, prediction

i have different log files like app logs, system log files, database log files etc. 
When a user request for some data then sometimes that user gets response very late. 
I will be calculating difference between request and response time and then need to predict that on which parameter from all these log files(app log, system log files, database log files) that delay depends.

Which spark machine learning algorithm would give best result to predict the variable which causes delay between request and response time??

Answer (score 0):

It may be one or more variables. Before getting stuck into ML algrorithms, do a quick scatter plot of variables vs delay - you might find your answer very quickly. Failing that, you will need to use some kind of regression approach. Without knowing all of the details, it is tricky to suggest exactly how you would construct a solution.

Comment: Thanks Ben Horsburgh.. I will first try with scatter plot.